# Android custom Action bar issue

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am working on Custom `ActionBar` and using below code :

```
   ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
   actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

   LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) this
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   customView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.action_bar_title, null);
   actionBar.setCustomView(customView);
   actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM
                | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

but facing extra space issue on right side so please check screen shot for      selected area.

[image]

Comment: post your code of custom layout.

Comment: I am not able to paste complete code so please check link:
http://pastebin.com/vRTLXir2

Comment: remove settings item from menu xml, if you have

Comment: I have already removed settings item but layout looking perfect when I am trying in main activity with toolbar
 toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
  setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
but not for other activity.

Answer (score 0):

some month ago i also faced this problem after that i found this solution. there is one trick you can resolve this issue, I know that is not right answer but by some logic you can get what you want.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/addItem"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/add" />
```

or do one thing you can put your add and info button to linearlayout and give right alignment as true,i am not sure about this but you should try once.

Comment: its worked for me,only you have to remove right margin from add imageview and increase the width and height by 10dp because we are going to add padding by 10dp or 5dp.

Comment: try like this                                                                               <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/info"
        android:id="@+id/ivInfo"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

Comment: Layout is fine but when to try in AppCompatActivity then it has extra space. But for main mainactivity it's looking fine, don't know why?